# get Id of the rows which were updated by query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I want to get the primary key column value for the rows which were affected by query in Java. I am using MySql DB. Suppose query is like,

```
update user set pincode = 390023 where area like '%ABC Road%'
```

Then in java, I want the ids of each row (Primary key of each row) updated. Something that can be possible with Statement object in Java may be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the rows just before you update them. 
Use `select id from user where area like '%ABC Road%'`.

Remember to enclose those two operations in transaction to avoid row changes between those two.

Comment: k...so it is not possible to get those ids after update...like after insert we can get id using getGeneratedKeys() method of Statement....

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't. As far as I know Mysql can just return last inserted row id.

Comment: For insert yes you can get the Id if primary column is set to auto increment......

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id FROM user WHERE area LIKE '%ABC Road%';
```

or alternative way:

```
SET @ids = NULL;

UPDATE user
SET pincode = 390023
WHERE area LIKE '%ABC Road%'
      AND (SELECT @ids := CONCAT_WS(',', id, @ids));

SELECT @ids;
```